# Reshape JSON data with nested fields, using paths

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonpath

I need to reshape (rename / move fields) JSON data files which contains nested fields but finds it quite difficult (or particularly ugly) using Jackson.

For example if I have JSON lines which look like this :

```
[
  {"id": 5, "date": "20180301", "meta": {"other_meta": "aze", "z": 1}
  ...
]
```

and a mapping with some kind of xpath to reshape the JSON :

```
old_field  new_field
"/id": "/id"
"/date": "/meta/date"
"/meta/z": "/z"
"/meta": "/metadata"
```

The result would look like this :

```
[
  {"id": 5, "z": 1, "metadata": {"date": "20180301", "other_meta": "aze"}
  ...
]
```

It's of course a simple example but we can imagine more complex reshaping.

Is there a Java library able to make transformations like this using paths (or not, could be another way of writing the mapping) and possibly compatible with Jackson object model ? I looked a bit around JsonPath but couldn't find a clear way to do it. If there is an elegant solution (or at least not too dirty) using Jackson I would have missed, it would be great too.

Thanks !

Comment: You might consider JOLT http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception its like XSLT for JSON.

Comment: Also vote to close because asking to recommend a lib.

Comment: Thanks I'd look into JOLT. I do not ask necessarily to recommand a lib (whats the matter of asking it btw?) it could also be using Jackson.

Comment: recommending tools is just not what SO is for. You can read about it on the meta site if you like. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource